# How do you query for a block inside of search results?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say you have this table:

```
var query = db.Cars.OrderBy(u => u.Name);

ID      Name
17      Accord
772     Civic
36      F-150
2237    Model 3
425     Sienna
```

How would you grab the two rows that are after ID=772, while it is ordered by name like this?  These are the desired results:

```
ID      Name
36      F-150
2237    Model 3
425     Sienna
```

Comment: [425, Sienna] is also after ID=772. Why is it not in your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easy if your requirement was:

> Give me all cars with a Name alphabetically higher than "Civic"

(or higher than some input variable)

```
return db.Cars.Where(car.Name > "Civic")
              .OrderBy(car.Name);
```

Apparently, you have a requirement that is a quite unusual.

> Given some input car id (772), give me all Cars with a name alphabetically higher than the name the car with this id.

Because you access a database, you can't use SkipWhile, it is not supported for IQueryable.

```
string nameOfCar772 = db.Cars.Where(car => car.Id == 772)
                             .Select(car => car.Name)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
// TODO: handle if there is no car with id 772, so if car772 == null
return db.Cars.Where(car => car.Name > nameOfCar772)
                               .OrderBy(car => car.Name);
```

Alas, this takes two database accesses.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`SkipWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=netframework-4.8) method

```
var query = db.Cars.OrderBy(u => u.Name)
    .SkipWhile(u => u.Id != 772)
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(2);
```

Comment: Alas, SkipWhile is only supported as enumerable, not as queryable